# Mongo aggregation query to filter records with minimum amount and number of records for one user

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to filter records with condition of **each user having minimum number of 7 transaction in a month and each transaction being greater than 1000**. I have the below json after 2nd stage of pipeline after filtering out kind of transaction i want, getting month out of date and using groupby to get count of transaction by each user in a month. I am not able to apply the above condition to get the required data after that.

Sample Json:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 2,
        "sender" : "123dd3"
    },
    "data" : [
        {
            "name" : "name1",
            "amount" : 1000,
            "sender" : {
              "id" : "123455",
                "name" : "send 02",
                "phone" : "1234567"
            },
            "service" : "109",
            "createdAt" : "2020-02-07T16:24:56.047+06:30",
            "month" : 2
        },
        {
            "name" : "name1",
            "amount" : 10400,
            "sender" : {
              "id" : "123455",
                "name" : "send 02",
                "phone" : "1234567"
            },
            "service" : "109",
            "createdAt" : "2020-02-07T16:25:22.019+06:30",
            "month" : 2
        },
        {
            "name" : "name1",
            "amount" : 10400,
            "sender" : {
              "id" : "123455",
                "name" : "send 02",
                "phone" : "1234567"
            },
            "service" : "109",
            "createdAt" : "2020-02-07T16:26:16.703+06:30",
            "month" : 2
        }
    ],
    "count" : 3
}
```

My Query:

```
[{
    $match: {
        service: '109'
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "month": {
            "$month": "$createdAt"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            'month': '$month',
            'sender': '$sender.id'
        },
        data: {
            $push: '$$ROOT'
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        '_id': 1,
        'data': 1,
        'count': 1,
        'cond': {
            $cond: [{
                $gte: ["$data.amount", 1000]
            }, true, false]
        }
    }
}]
```

I am not able to get the required condition right, as there are **multiple records under data and i need to apply this condition to each one of them and with number of transaction being greater than equal to 7**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) your `data` array first and then run [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to see if there's more than 7 items

```
{
    $project: {
        '_id': 1,
        'data': 1,
        'count': 1,
        'cond': {
            $gte: [
                { $size: { $filter: { input: "$data", cond: { $gte: [ "$$this.amount", 1000 ] } } } },
                7
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting error : message" : "Missing 'in' parameter to $map"

Comment: @RahulAnand sorry, please try now

Comment: It's working, to apply condition for minimum count 7, i should try using $cond operator in the project block or add a new block for it?

Comment: This will look for all the elements in the array, but i need to have at least 7 records with 1000 and above. I.e if there are 9 records out of which 7 records are of 1200 and 2 records are of value 500. Then this should be as one out the result.